# UIButton and action for "next' and previous image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uibutton, ibaction

So, pretty new to iPhone dev and learning all the time. I know what I want but dont quite know where to start. I have really only dealt with tableView apps before this project so my practical knowledge of imageView's and custom actions is very much lacking!

I want to have a UIImageView loaded with an image  (using an array populated by a fetchedResultsController as images will be stored in a CoreData DB ).

I want an UIButton with action "next" and UIButton with action "previous" which will control the previously mentioned imageViews' displayed image.

Thus far I have the DB mapped and interface design but am failing to find this answer to these points (I am sure it will be fairly straight forward to those who know).

Any advise or example code would be greatly appreciated.

DetartrateD

@shawnwall  code snippet from below...

```
-(IBAction)nextImage { 
    index++; 
    int imageCount=31; 
    if (index<=imageCount) { 
        NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i.jpg", index];
        [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]]; 
    } 
}
```

Mutatable array seeded in viewDidLoad:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Images"      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"topImage" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResultsT = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResultsT == nil) {
}

[self setTopImageArray:mutableFetchResultsT];

NSLog(@"%i" , [topImageArray count]);
```

Image being added to array here:

```
Images *imageS = (Images *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Images" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

imageS.topImage = selectedImage;


[topImageArray insertObject:imageS.topImage atIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%i" , [topImageArray count]);
```

...
...

Same method but after I have created a thumbnail i call:

```
[self updateTopIV];
```

Which is :

```
-(void)updateTopIV 
{
topIV.image = [topImageArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

I then have the 2 action buttons (next/previous):

```
- (IBAction)nextTouch
{
[self showPhoto:1]; 
}

- (IBAction)previousTouch
{
[self showPhoto:-1];
}


 - (void)showPhoto:(NSInteger)numberToAdd
{
    topIV.image = [topImageArray objectAtIndex:currentPhotoIndex + numberToAdd];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the images in an array, and have the current image's index in a variable

```
NSInteger *currentPhotoIndex;

- (IBAction)nextTouch
{
    [self showPhoto:1]; // number to add to current, so 1 for next, -1 for previous
}

- (IBAction)previousTouch
{
    [self showPhoto:-1];
}


// Actual "Logic"

- (void)showPhoto:(NSInteger)numberToAdd
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages = allTheImagesYouWantToShow
    UIImageView.image = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:currentPhotoIndex + numberToAdd];
    // Adding one or subtracting one from the current image's index will show the photo
    immediately before or after it. With this method, you can also skip around to any
    number you want.
}
```

I think that should do it.

--
EDIT:

currentPhotoIndex should be defined in your header file as you have done. It should be set to the position in the array of the first image you show. For now, lets assume it's the first one.

The first time that you show an image, do this:

```
currentPhotoIndex = [arrayOfImages indexOfObject:thePhotoI'mShowingRightNow];
```

Also, good catch. In order to prevent the NSInteger from being out of the array's bounds, you need something like this:

```
- (void)showPhoto:(NSInteger)numberToAdd
{
    if (currentPhotoIndex > 0 && < arrayOfImages.count) // Makes sure that the int is within the array
    {
        // Show new image
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your generous input buddy. Working on getting the images retrieved from a core data store to put in a mutable array at the minute (sigh.....) will give it a blast when I have passed this hurdle!

Comment: its not happening buddy :(. I have added further code snippets above to clarify how my set up if working. I dont understand how the value for currentPhotoIndex is defined (I have added an NSUInteger to the h.) Also, when the next and previous falls outside of the array, how would you stop this?

Comment: forgot to accept your working answer, my bad dude, thanks for the advice which did work !

Answer (score 1):

Place two UIButton's in your view in a .xib (if you are using IB).

Create two IBAction's in your view controller .h:

```
-(IBAction)nextClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)prevClicked:(id)sender;
```

and .m:

```
-(IBAction)nextClicked:(id)sender
{
  //do stuff
  imageView.image = whatever;
}

-(IBAction)prevClicked:(id)sender
{
  //do stuff
  imageView.image = whatever;
}
```

Next, link those actions to the 'touch up inside' event of the buttons via IB. This will make these events fire.

Comment: Nice one shawnwall! Thats the first step √. Now any ideas on generating the logic for the action? I have found this which appears to do sort of what I require but I will not have a static number of images as the user will be able to add images <code>{
static int index = 0;  // <-- here
    index++;
    // Set imageCount to as many images as are available
    int imageCount=31;
    if (index<=imageCount) {
        NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i.jpg", index];
        [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
    }
}
<code/>

Comment: just grab the array count using [arrayOfImages count].